# Context menu on the top

Tags: android, contextmenu

Is it possible to hide the context menu (select all, copy find ...) that appears above a WebView on longpress and keep the selection on Android 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass and extend WebView so that you could override `OnLongClick`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but if i disable long press i can't select a text, i want use the quick action when i select text not action bar , is it possible to hide context menu with (select all, copy, find ...)?

Comment: I fixed my answer for you hicham to reflect your new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source code which is availble for free and create your own WebView class or extend the WebView and Override the function that calls the cut/copy/paste window to appear.

Comment: Can you please spell out where the source code for cut/copy/paste?